# Output status message about Bluetooth in ViewController.swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm create app only for me. Nad create it with MVC.

And i have this peace of code in my model "BTData.swift":

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
    switch (central.state)
    {
    case .Unsupported:
        println("BLE не поддерживается")
        break
    case .Unauthorized:
        println("Приложение не авторизовано для использования BLE")
        break
    case .Unknown:
        println("Состояние Central Manager не известно")
        break
    case .Resetting:
        println("Соединение с системным сервисом потеряно")
        break
    case .PoweredOff:
        println("BLE выключено")
        break
    case .PoweredOn:
        startScanning()
    default:
        break
    }
}

func startScanning() {
    println("Scanning...")
    if let central = centralManager {
        central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    }
}
```

All works good in debug. I saw this messages there.
But i can't understand how to output State status message in the label.

Comment: From your question, your problem isn't clear; however from your comment on the deleted answer it is more clear.  You should add that comment to your question to explain your problem more clearly.   You need to look at either a protocol/delegate (if only one object at a time needs to get the information) or using NSNotifications (if you want to notify an arbitrary number)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm update my question.

Answer (score 0):

I got to do with NSNotification.
Here code for model:

```
func sendBTServiceNotification(BTStatus: String) {
    var connectionDetails = ["Статус": BTStatus]
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(BLEServiceStatusNotification, object: self, userInfo: connectionDetails)
}

// Получаем состояние при обновлении Central Manager (обязательная)
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
    switch (central.state)
    {
    case .Unsupported:
        sendBTServiceNotification("BLE не поддерживается")
        break
    case .Unauthorized:
        sendBTServiceNotification("Приложение не авторизовано для использования BLE")
        break
    case .Unknown:
        sendBTServiceNotification("Состояние Central Manager не известно")
        break
    case .Resetting:
        sendBTServiceNotification("Соединение с системным сервисом потеряно")
        break
    case .PoweredOff:
        sendBTServiceNotification("BLE выключено")
        break
    case .PoweredOn:
        startScanning()
    default:
        break
    }
}

func startScanning() {
    sendBTServiceNotification("Сканирование...")
    if let central = centralManager {
        central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    }
}
```

And this code for ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    btData = BTData()

    // Читаем статус BLE
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("statusChanged:"), name: btData.BLEServiceStatusNotification, object: nil)

}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: btData.BLEServiceStatusNotification, object: nil)
}

// Обновляем статус BLE
func statusChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo as! [String: String]
    let statusMsg: String! = userInfo["Статус"]
    Status.text = "Статус: \(statusMsg)"
}
```